# How to improve performance getting recent records to display in list, recent top 5 most

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

I'm making a sample recent screen that will display a list, it displays the list, with `id` set as primary key.

I have done the correct query as expected but the table with big amount of data can cause slow performance issues.

This is the sample query below:

```
SELECT  distinct H.id    -- (Primary Key),
        H.partnerid as PartnerId,
        H.partnername AS partner, H.accountname AS accountName,
        H.accountid as AccountNo,
    FROM  myschema.mytransactionstable H
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  S.accountid, S.partnerid, S.accountname,
                max(S.transdate) AS maxDate
            from  myschema.mytransactionstable S
            group by  S.accountid, S.partnerid, S.accountname
               ) ms  ON H.accountid = ms.accountid
      AND  H.partnerid = ms.partnerid
      AND  H.accountname =ms.accountname
      AND  H.transdate = maxDate
    WHERE  H.accountid = ms.accountid
      AND  H.partnerid = ms.partnerid
      AND  H.accountname = ms.accountname
      AND  H.transdate = maxDate
    GROUP BY  H.partnerid,H.accountid, H.accountname
    ORDER BY  H.id DESC
    LIMIT  5
```

In my case, there are values which are similar in the selected columns but differ only in their id's

Below is a link to an image without executing the query above. They are all the records that have not yet been filtered.
[Sample result query click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfQQR.png)

Since I only want to get the 5 most recent by their `id` but the other columns can contain similar values
`accountname,accountid,partnerid`.

I already got the correct query but,
I want to improve the performance of the query. Any suggestions for the improvement of query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't repeat ON and WHERE clauses.  Use `ON` to say how the tables (or subqueries) are "related"; use `WHERE` for filtering (that is, which rows to keep).  Probably in your case, all the `WHERE` should be removed.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`
- This 'composite' index would probably help because of dealing with the subquery and the `JOIN`:

  ```
    INDEX(partnerid, accountid, accountname, transdate)
  ```
- That would also avoid a separate sort for the `GROUP BY`.
- But then the `ORDER BY` is different, so it cannot avoid a sort.
- This *might* avoid the sort without changing the result set ordering: `ORDER BY partnerid, accountid, accountname, transdate DESC`
- Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` if you have further questions.

If we cannot get an index to handle the WHERE, GROUP BY, *and* ORDER BY, the query will generate all the rows before seeing the `LIMIT 5`.  If the index does work, then the *outer* query will stop after 5 -- potentially a big savings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(order by transdate desc) as rn
from myschema.mytransactionstable
)A where rn<=5
```

Comment: Already solved before you answered.... Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: @joshuamark If it's solved , don't waste everyone's time by leaving it open. Either delete or answer and 'accept' (once sufficient time has passed)